# $CNOT$ teleportation in ZX-calculus: how to simplify my circuit further?

Tags: teleportation, zx-calculus

I am stuck in simplyfing the following cNOT teleportation in ZX-calculus. I don't know how to proceed further. The circuit I start from is taken from [this thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.07908) (Fig 2.14, page 22).

Which property can I use to simplify the circuit further? Am I forced to sit down and compute the matrix product?

In case the image is not super clear, in d), the element in the bottom green Z spider is $(-1)^{b_1} \pi b_2$ (I could have removed the $(-1)^{b_1}$ already as it is multiplied by $\pi$ but I kept it to be sure you see my step-by-step calculation).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see where you went wrong. In ZX-Calculus, only connectivity matters. So in your final stage, you can connect the middle two phaseless nodes with a vertical line, instead of the cup. Then, removing the middle two phaseless nodes using the identity rule, you are left with a CNOT gate.

Comment: Ooh right. It was actually very simple. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).